# NLTK TweetTokennizer is not workin on google colab notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I have downloaded all the packages of NLTK with the command of `nltk.download()`.
but the thing is that when I try to import `TweetTokenizer` I get the error.

```
tokenizer = TweetTokenizer(preserve_case=False, strip_handles=True, reduce_len=True)
tweet_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet2)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'TweetTokenizer' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

`nltk.download()` is not for importing packages but for downloading respective corpora and modules. Details found [here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/downloader.html).

You still have to import the modules. For this you will have to use `from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer`. Details found [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

Comment: Welcome, Do mark the answer if it helped you solve your problem, as it encourages me to help you in the future. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not imported the `TweetTokenizer`. Try:

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
```

Comment: Great to hear. Could you please accept one of the answers (grey tick mark on the left from the answer) and / or upvote the answers?